# How to use small (thumbnail size) image as a button - to load a full screen image? Or Touch Event?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, touch-event

I'm pretty new to objective and I'm trying to enhance an iPhone app (coding done by someone else). I'm trying to pull an image from the internet and its displayed as a thumbnail (like in the iphone address book app).

I would like to have the user touch the small image and it changes to a full sized image. I've seen touch events on some tutorials but I have no idea why it's not working for me.

This is in my .m file to pull the image from some website:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    urlImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Koala_with_young.ogv/seek%3D3.5-Koala_with_young.ogv.jpg"]]];
}
```

Other than that I am uncertain how to use an image from url with the touch event, sadly all the tutorials are mostly about a static image.

I tried to create a subclass of UIView but I couldn't connect the image to the IBOutlet. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch.view isEqual:imageViewObject])
{
   //maximize the image here
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm..that didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, is there anything I should do before using this code? Thanks!